# Upgrading to  Drupal 7.7 produces a fatal error: What can I do?

Tags: 7, updating

I have upgraded my local site to Drupal 7.7 from Drupal 7.4, following the instructions in [How to upgrade Drupal 7 to Drupal 7.2](http://drtbalu.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/how-to-upgrade-drupal-7-to-drupal-7-2/).

Before I could use update.php, visiting my site got me this message on every page of the site:

> Fatal error: Class 'DatabaseConnection' not found in C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Sites\accountablog\includes\database\database.inc on line 17

Doing a database restore did nothing to alleviate the problem.
What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The [database.inc](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob_plain/ca9434462a4af269f24b0b616939938a3a4c112f:/includes/database/database.inc) file does contain the definition of the class `DatabaseConnection`.

```
/**
 * Base Database API class.
 *
 * This class provides a Drupal-specific extension of the PDO database
 * abstraction class in PHP. Every database driver implementation must provide a
 * concrete implementation of it to support special handling required by that
 * database.
 *
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
 */
abstract class DatabaseConnection extends PDO {
  // …
}
```

It is probable the file was not correctly copied, or has been corrupted during the copy; that would explain why the class has not been found, but the class is effectively present in the file that comes with Drupal 7.

Comment: Recopied, and worked! I was freaking out. Thank you.